# str_replace back into variable

Tags: php

I have a string:

```
$ht="Sunday_ Oct. 31_ 2012"
```

I want to replace underscores with commas

I can do:

```
echo "-------------------->>>".str_replace("_", ",", $ht);
```

and it works fine like that, but I don't want to echo it, I want it back in $ht.

Maybe something like

```
 $ht=str_replace("_",",",$ht)
```

which don't work.

Thanks in advance,

alan

Answer (score 2):

Simply:

```
$ht = str_replace("_", ",", $ht);
```

And it ***does*** work:

```
$ht="Sunday_ Oct. 31_ 2012";
$ht = str_replace("_", ",", $ht);
echo $ht; // Sunday, Oct. 31, 2012
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you forgot the `;`?
Because this should work just fine:

```
$ht = str_replace("_", ",", $ht);
```

[<sup>View the output on codepad</sup>](http://codepad.org/sHH8RKgt)

---

Side-note: You should work on your coding style, in this case:

- spaces before and after the `=` character
- a space after every function parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Strtr is faster than str_replace because it replaces 1 character with 1 character:

```
$ht = strtr($ht, '_', ',');
```

You should use str_replace if you want to replace more than 1 character with any number of characters.